# C parser warnings: virtual object addresses

Tags: c, visual-studio-2005, warnings

In a C project, I deal with a large header file including all shared declarations. The newest version that was delivered to me brings up parser warnings I do not understand:

```
1>someheader.h(2487) : warning: Error parsing virtual object addresses specified! Ignoring!
1>someheader.h(2487) : warning: Ignoring XXX_SomeTypename virtual instance name(s) specifed, as no corresponding virtual address specified!
```

Btw - the compiler is Visual Studio 2005.
The respective line is the last line of a typedef as in the example below:

```
typedef struct
{
    float member;
} Typename_t; /* @vaddr:XXX_XXX @cycleid:YYY_YYY @vname:XXX_SomeTypename */
```

I have no clue what this warning means and the generic searches (SO, google) did not provide *any* results. Could somebody assist to find out what might be wrong there?

Comment: This may seem as linker/memory issue. Maybe not enough ram for code ? But this is just my speculations.

Comment: Many thanks for looking into this. Unfortunately, I had to learn that the parser warning actually stem from a third party software that does additional parsing in a build step I was not aware of :( . Sorry for taking up your time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP comments that the parser warning actually stemmed from a third party software that does additional parsing in a build step OP was not aware of.